# Static Pages, RoR Apps, Forms and Databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, static, controllers

I brought in a static website into a brand new RoR app. I dropped the entire directory into the public folder so I wouldn't have to change the application layout. I now want to capture data from one of the static pages forms...I have the following code in the static page but it's not correctly saving to the database.

```
#public/test/index.html
<form action="resellers#create" method="post">
<label>
    <input id="number" type="text" placeholder="Enter number"/>
</label>
<label>
    <input id="type" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resellers#create` isn't an actual form action that you can submit to in a browser. That's just the way Rails refers to it in its routes. What you'll need to do is  run `rake routes`, or if you're using RoR 4+, visit `/rails/info/routes` in development mode to see what route `resellers#create` is actually pointing to, probably `POST /resellers`.

However, unless you specifically set it in your configuration, you can't submit to the form because Rails is smart and wants a secure token for each form submission to prevent forgeries and other nasty things. You're much better off having your static website point to the form and just making a route to the form look like it's part of your static website.

Comment: Sorry, can you go into a little more detail about having the static website point to the form?

Comment: and yes, your correct resellers#create is pointing to POST/reselelrs

Comment: What I was basically saying was you would need to create the form in Rails because of security considerations, and then have a route (in `routes.rb`) for that form, if you care that it looks like your static website links.

Comment: but i want the form to be built in to the static page? could you give me a example please. i'm having trouble understanding.

Comment: See my second paragraph. Rails specifically doesn't let outside forms submit to the server by way of secure tokens so that someone malicious can't send you bad data and screw up your system. Check out [this section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf) of the Rails security guide.

Comment: im misunderstanding this, I am trying to keep the current form (built in the static pages) to save this data to the database.

Comment: You can do that, but if you want to do that, you have to turn off certain security features in Rails according to the guide from my previous comment. However, it's *strongly* recommended not to do that so that you don't have security issues.